# Webbrowser control (Office/Access 2010) & CSS rounded corners

Tags: css, vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control

I would like to get rounded corners in webbrowser control on a form in Office/Access 2010. I have created the following testcode:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim doc As IHTMLDocument

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim htm$

    Webbrowser0.Object.Navigate2 "about:blank"
    WaitForReady
    Set doc = Webbrowser0.Object.Document
    htm = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>"
    htm = htm & "<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge"">"
    htm = htm & "<meta charset=""utf-8"">"
    htm = htm & "<meta http-equiv=""cache-control"" content=""no-cache"" />"
    htm = htm & "<style type=""text/css"" media=""all"">"
    htm = htm & ".test { background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; border-top-left-radius: 15px; }"
    htm = htm & "</style>"
    htm = htm & "</head>"
    htm = htm & "<body>"
    htm = htm & "<div class=""test"">Test</div>"
    htm = htm & "</body>"
    doc.write htm
End Sub
Private Sub WaitForReady()
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Webbrowser0.ReadyState >= READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
End Sub
```

The page is generated, the most CSS are correctly rendered. But the property for rounded corners is ignored and only rendered after pressing F5 (reloading the page). The html-source code after F5 is of course the same, only the rendering is different. How can I fix this (without editing the registry)? What is the reason for this behavior? In my opinion the control should be rendered the CSS-property or not, and not only after a refresh?!

When I copy the html-sourcecode in a single htm-File and execute it in IE, the rendering looks like well at the first time.

Have anyone an idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: I have found a workarround: Webbrowser0.Object.refresh after doc.write. It works, but it is´nt a clean solution ...

Comment: Have you read this article [Specifying IE Version WebBControl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version)?